# What is the dart equivalent to Swift “extensions”?

Tags: android, ios, swift, dart, flutter

Keyword/reserved word `extension` allow code to be much cleaner by using an existing class in the standard frameworks without subclassing them.
Is there a keyword in Dart that allows the same behavior?

```
extension Double {
    var mm: Double { return self / 1_000.0 }
}

let oneInch = 25.4.mm
print("One inch is \(oneInch) meters")
```

Comment: it seems that its not implemented yet: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/40 https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/42. What about extending the type?

Comment: I found that `extension` in swift allows code to be much clearer, which is something that type extension doesn't provide. It is good to know there is an open issue on the improvement. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

They are finally here

From dart version 2.6 (not 100% sure).

```
class Foo {
  printFoo()  {
    print("Foo");
  }
}

extension Bar on Foo { 
  printBar()  {
    print("Bar");
  }
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo();
  foo.printFoo();
  foo.printBar();
}
```

prints:

> Foo
>
> Bar

You can give it a try in [dart pad.](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are currently being implemented into the language.

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/projects/1#card-18758939

Specifications document

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/static-extension-methods/feature-specification.md

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Sadly, Dart doesn't support extension methods.

In the Dart repository, there's an [issue about how to add new functionality to existing types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/40) for that.
More specifically, there are issues for [extension methods](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/41) and [extension types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/42).

Of course, you can always use new `class`es that `extend` existing classes introduce new functionality on top of them.
However, that only works for non-primitive classes, so let's hope for the best.
Your best shot probably is to upvote the issues linked above.